# avoid submit form on enter keypress and run function on enter

Tags: angular

I'm working on angular 13, I was trying to get data from the user
I use the carousel in the form to display each input on different carousel slides.
when the user enters data and presses enter button form gets submitted.
so I was trying to prevent submit on entering and on enter show next slide.

```
<form
  #bankData="ngForm"
  id="bankData"
  (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()"
  (keyup.enter)="goToNext()"
  (ngSubmit)="GetRequiredData(bankData.value)"
  method="post"
>
```

```
goToNext() {
    
    this.ngCarousel.next();
  }
```

here I was trying to prevent submit and on keyup display next slide.
its work, but when I press enter, its slide 2 slider and display 3rd slide

Comment: if the problem still occurring please prove `stackblitz` example and I will do my best to help you.

Comment: Can you show your `goToNext` method please

Comment: @Alexis please check now, i have updated my question

Comment: @rahulgupta it will be easier if you could create a reproduction of your issue, with [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) for example

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways to solve the issue:

1. add `type="button"` at the submit button in the form
2. check inside GetRequiredData if the form is valid before you send it.
3. disable the click if form not valid
   (here you should add ng class so the button will be with lower opacity to indicate the user he cant press)
   hopes this helps if solution 1 don't work try to remove the `ngsubmit` from the form tag.

further information:

[angular form validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation)

[angular forms docs](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview)

Comment: i want to submit data without any submit button
once a user clicks on last data radio button form will submit

Comment: remove  ng submit from form and once the last data radio pressed check if form valid then call ur submit function. since you don't have a btn you need to check each radio btn if the form is done since user can press last radio btn before others

Comment: user cant reach the last radio button until they fill all input data